# Remove underline on hover for jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Is it possible to remove the underline (text-decoration:none) for the jquery ui accordion?

I tried many different solutions, but none seem to work. Maybe I am not selecting the proper style id.

For example...

```
$('#accordion .ui-state-hover').attr('style', 'text-decoration:none');
$('#accordion .ui-state-focus').attr('style', 'text-decoration:none');
$('#accordion .ui-state-hover').css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

EDIT: I understand that I can just change the CSS stylesheet, but I only want to do this for ONE of the many accordions.

EDIT2: Here is the actual code...

```
<style type="text/css">
.myAccordion.ui-state-hover, .myAccordion.ui-state-focus {text-decoration:none !important;}
</style>

<!--Downtime Announcement begin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                active: false
            });
            $('#accordion .ui-icon').attr('style', 'display: none');
            $('#accordion .ui-accordion-header').attr('style', 'background:#A4000F');
            $('#accordion .ui-accordion-header a').attr('style', 'font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;color:white');
            $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content').attr('style', 'background:#A4000F;width:auto');
            $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content p').attr('style', 'font: 14px/16px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:white');
            $('#accordion .ui-state-hover').addClass('myAccordion');
            $('#accordion .ui-state-focus').addClass('myAccordion');

        });
    </script>

    <div id="accordion" >
        <h3><a href="#">Important Announcement</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Beginning at 6pm EDT on April 1st, 2011 our websites will be down for a system upgrade. Please return later in the weekend when the site will return to full availability.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Downtime Announcement end-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the [stylesheet](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming) that comes with jQuery UI.

Comment: I do not want to modify the stylesheet because then it will change that for ALL of the accordions I have on the site. I only want to change it for ONE accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#accordion .ui-state-hover').css('text-decoration','none');
```

**Edit after few comments:**

When you don't want to modify all accordions, then just create new css class ie. "myAccordion", then use jquery to addClass to those two selectors.

```
$('#accordion .ui-state-hover').addClass('myAccordion');
$('#accordion .ui-state-focus').addClass('myAccordion');
```

And modify stylesheet like:

```
.myAccordion.ui-state-hover, .myAccordion.ui-state-focus {text-decoration:none;}
```

If this rule isn't strong enugh, then modify:

```
.myAccordion.ui-state-hover, .myAccordion.ui-state-focus {text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Comment: Then just open accordion's stylesheet file. Find those two classes and add text-decoration:none; to both.

Comment: Weird. Do you have it online? Some real code would be nice.. hard to guess like this.

Comment: This doesn't help that much. I would have to download all files and set it up at local and I can't do that now. But I checked the demo at [link](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/) but there isn't any underline. If you can't show that code live, then maybe you could at least show html code of that element, that you are talking about, and also applied styles, that can be seen in firebug. Probably easiest way would be running your page at your localhost in firefox, use Firebug with Inspect element and printscreen result.

Comment: Also checking the demo... the styles should be applied to anchors, not divs. So $('#accordion .ui-accordion a').css('text-decoration','none');

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, it seems the underline is on the anchor element. So, just use this as CSS:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or via script as:

```
$('#accordion .ui-accordion-header a').css('text-decoration','none');
```

I set this up on jsFiddle for a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/93hw2. I'm sure this will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

did u try this:

```
$('#accordion .ui-state-hover').css('text-decoration', 'none');
$('#accordion .ui-state-focus').css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

remember to do that **AFTER** the load of the accordion